# XSLT: Concatenation of looping list items separated by pipe symbol

Tags: xml, xslt, string-concatenation, templating

I am trying to build an XML output using XSLT templating The XML has multiple Group GroupName="PersonalSocialMedia" items in which each item do have multiple group items.

My input XML looks like this :

```
<FormData>     
     <Group GroupName="PersonalSocialMedia" Array="true">
            <GroupItem>
              <Element Name="itemID">2</Element>
              <Element Name="NomineePersonalSocialMedia">
                <Code>2</Code>
                <Value>Instagram</Value>
              </Element>
              <Element Name="NomineeSocialMediaUserName">Iuname</Element>
            </GroupItem>
            <GroupItem>
              <Element Name="itemID">1</Element>
              <Element Name="NomineePersonalSocialMedia">
                <Code>1</Code>
                <Value>Facebook</Value>
                </Element>
              <Element Name="NomineeSocialMediaUserName">fname</Element>
            </GroupItem>
          </Group>
          <Group GroupName="PersonalSocialMedia" Array="true">
            <GroupItem>
              <Element Name="itemID">3</Element>
              <Element Name="NomineePersonalSocialMedia">
                <Code>3</Code>
                <Value>LinkedIn</Value>
              </Element>
              <Element Name="NomineeSocialMediaUserName">testname1</Element>
            </GroupItem>
            <GroupItem>
              <Element Name="itemID">2</Element>
              <Element Name="NomineePersonalSocialMedia">
                <Code>4</Code>
                <Value>Twitter</Value>
         </Element>
              <Element Name="NomineeSocialMediaUserName">testname2</Element>
        </GroupItem>
        <GroupItem>
            <Element Name="itemID">1</Element>
            <Element Name="NomineePersonalSocialMedia">
                <Code>1</Code>
                <Value>Facebook</Value>
            </Element>
            <Element Name="NomineeSocialMediaUserName">testname3</Element>
        </GroupItem>
    </Group>
</FormData>
```

And I would like to build my resultant XML to look like this; that is combining all the Value node inside the Element name "NomineePersonalSocialMedia" under each Groupitem separated by a comma and again combining these values with the items coming under the root node Groupname="PersonalSocialMedia" separated by a pipe symbol. But some how multilevel templating is not working as expected

```
<PersonalSocialMedia>
   Instagram, Facebook | LinkedIn, Twitter, Facebook
</PersonalSocialMedia>
```

This is the XSLT that i am applying to achieve the required output

```
<PersonalSocialMedia>
    <xsl:attribute name="Category">Nominee''s preferred personal social media network</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="Append">
            <xsl:with-param name="List" select="Group[@GroupName=''Nominees'']/GroupItem/Element[@Name=''PersonalSocialMedia'']/Value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="Group[@GroupName=''Nominees'']/GroupItem/Group[@GroupName=''PersonalSocialMedia'']/GroupItem">
        <xsl:call-template name="SocialMediaAppend">
            <xsl:with-param name="List" select="Element[@Name=''NomineePersonalSocialMedia'']/Value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:call-template name="SocialMediaAppend">
        <xsl:with-param name="List" select="Group[@GroupName=''PersonalSocialMedia'']/GroupItem" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</PersonalSocialMedia>
```

Template:

This is the template that is been called to build the required resultset.

```
<xsl:template name="SocialMediaAppend">
    <xsl:param name="List" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$List">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"> | </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Right now the template returns wrong resultset. I could generate the expected resultset with single group item but when there are multiple it is returning wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your code sample using XSLT version 1.0, you can apply the following templates (I replaced unknown code with `...`):

```
<xsl:template match="/FormData">
  <PersonalSocialMedia>
    ...
    <xsl:for-each select="Group[@GroupName='PersonalSocialMedia']">
        <xsl:call-template name="SocialMediaAppend">         <!-- Call with all 'Value's -->
            <xsl:with-param name="List" select="GroupItem/Element[@Name='NomineePersonalSocialMedia']/Value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"> | </xsl:if>       <!-- Delimiter between 'Group's --> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </PersonalSocialMedia>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="SocialMediaAppend">
    <xsl:param name="List" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$List">
        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>        <!-- Delimiter between 'Value's -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Applying these templates to the XML gives the following result:

```
<PersonalSocialMedia>Instagram, Facebook | LinkedIn, Twitter, Facebook</PersonalSocialMedia>
```

---

You could simplify this by omitting the named template. So the template could look like:

```
<xsl:template match="/FormData">
  <PersonalSocialMedia>
    <xsl:for-each select="Group[@GroupName='PersonalSocialMedia']">
      <xsl:for-each select="GroupItem/Element[@Name='NomineePersonalSocialMedia']/Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"> | </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </PersonalSocialMedia>
</xsl:template>
```

The result stays the same. I cannot estimate if this would be an improvement to your code, so consider it to be a suggestion.